# Selenium getting text input of Twingly (Java Code)

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, iframe, element

Please check out the element of [this website.](https://www.twingly.com/ping)

It has a form, and along with 2 text input and 1 submit button.
I dont know which one from those 2 inputs that is actually used when the user type-in some urls over there.

But when I tried this (using **firefoxDriver**) to get the element:

```
WebElement textfieldURL = driver.findElement(By.id("ping-url")); // even ping-box not working
```

The result's unable to locate the element.

Then I change my code to this :

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("ping-iframe")));
WebElement textfieldURL = driver.findElement(By.id("ping-url")); // even ping-box not working
```

The result's still unable to locate the element.
Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned the `exception` which you are facing. As your `input` tag present under `iframe` so you need to first switch into frame and than have to perform actions -

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("ping-iframe"))); 
//or you can use frame index as well
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

your element  is available with the id `ping-box` . Try the following complete code -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:/Application/geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.twingly.com/ping");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("ping-iframe")));
driver.findElement(By.id("ping-box")).sendKeys("http://www.google.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("ping-button")).click();
```

Same is working for me.